# Multitasking in SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

In my simple code I create a circle with random color and opacity, which moves for a while and then disappears. It works as supposed.

```
class Circle1Thread extends Thread {

@Override 
public void run() {
    prev_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(running) {
            Canvas canvas = null;

                switch(state) {
                case States.NONE:
                    try {
                        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        if (!counted) {
                            width = canvas.getWidth();
                            height = canvas.getHeight();
                            counted = true;
                        }
                        got_direction = false;
                        paint = new Paint(); 
                        paint.setColor(States.getRandomColor()); // random color
                        paint.setAlpha(random.nextInt(250)); //random alpha
                        radius = (float) random.nextInt(width/4); // random radius
                        x = random.nextInt((int)(width-2*radius)) + radius; 
                        y = random.nextInt((int)(height-2*radius)) + radius; // random x & y positions
                        current_radius = 1;
                        synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, current_radius, paint); // draw almost unseen circle, than increasing its radius
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (canvas!= null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        else Log.d("canvas","canvas is null in thread 1");
                        state = States.APPEARING;
                        creation_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    break;
                case States.APPEARING:
                    if ((now_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - prev_time) >=15) {
                        current_radius = current_radius +3;
                        if (current_radius >=radius) {
                            state = States.MOVING;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                        try {
                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, current_radius, paint);
                            }
                        }
                        finally {
                            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            prev_time = now_time;
                        }
                    break;
                case States.MOVING:
                    if (!got_direction) {
                        direction = States.getDirection();
                        got_direction = true;
                    }
                    if (((now_time = System.currentTimeMillis()) - prev_time) >=15) {
                        switch(direction) {
                        case States.DIRECTION_DOWN:
                            y = y+2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_LEFT:
                            x =x-2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                            x = x+2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_UP:
                            y = y-2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if((now_time - creation_time) >=4000) {
                        state = States.DISAPPEARING;
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        prev_time = now_time;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.DISAPPEARING:
                    if ((now_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - prev_time) >=15) {
                        current_radius = current_radius -3;
                        if (current_radius <=1) {
                            state = States.NONE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                        try {
                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                                canvas.drawCircle(x, y, current_radius, paint);
                            }
                        }
                        finally {
                            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            prev_time = now_time;
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I have no idea how to create several circles, which would behave in a similar way. I tried making it that way, but it doesn't work properly.

```
class Circle1Thread extends Thread {

public Circle1Thread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceHolder = holder;
    random = new Random();
    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    running = run;
}

@Override 
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        for(int count=0; count<5; count++) {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            Log.d("canvas" ,"operating in count = "+String.valueOf(count));
            Canvas canvas = null;
            if (!was_created[count]) prev_time[count] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                switch(state[count]) {
                case States.NONE:
                    try {
                        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        if (!counted) {
                            width = canvas.getWidth();
                            height = canvas.getHeight();
                            counted = true;
                        }
                        got_direction[count] = false;
                        paint[count] = new Paint(); 
                        paint[count].setColor(States.getRandomColor()); // random color
                        paint[count].setAlpha(random.nextInt(250)); //random alpha
                        radius[count] = (float) random.nextInt(width/4); // random radius
                        x[count] = random.nextInt((int)(width-2*radius[count])) + radius[count]; 
                        y[count] = random.nextInt((int)(height-2*radius[count])) + radius[count]; // random x & y positions
                        current_radius[count] = 1;
                        was_created[count] = true;
                        synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                            Log.d("canvas","color drawn in count = "+String.valueOf(count));
                            canvas.drawCircle(x[count], y[count], current_radius[count], paint[count]); // draw almost unseen circle, than increasing its radius
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (canvas!= null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        else Log.d("canvas","canvas is null in thread 1");
                        state[count] = States.APPEARING;
                        creation_time[count] = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    break;
                case States.APPEARING:
                    if (((now_time[count] = System.currentTimeMillis()) - prev_time[count]) >=15) {
                        current_radius[count] = current_radius[count] +3;
                        Log.d("radius",String.valueOf(radius[count])+" in count = "+String.valueOf(count));
                        if (current_radius[count] >=radius[count]) {
                            state[count] = States.MOVING;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                        try {
                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                Log.d("canvas","appearing in count = "+String.valueOf(count)+", radius = "+String.valueOf(current_radius[count]));
                                canvas.drawCircle(x[count], y[count], current_radius[count], paint[count]);
                            }
                        }
                        finally {
                            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            prev_time[count] = now_time[count];
                        }
                    break;
                case States.MOVING:
                    if (!got_direction[count]) {
                        direction[count] = States.getDirection();
                        got_direction[count] = true;
                    }
                    if (((now_time[count] = System.currentTimeMillis()) - prev_time[count]) >=15) {
                        switch(direction[count]) {
                        case States.DIRECTION_DOWN:
                            y[count] = y[count]+2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_LEFT:
                            x[count] =x[count]-2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_RIGHT:
                            x[count] = x[count]+2;
                            break;
                        case States.DIRECTION_UP:
                            y[count] = y[count]-2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if((now_time[count] - creation_time[count]) >=4000) {
                        state[count] = States.DISAPPEARING;
                        break;
                    }
                    try {
                        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                            Log.d("canvas","moving in count = "+String.valueOf(count));
                            canvas.drawCircle(x[count], y[count], radius[count], paint[count]);
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                        prev_time = now_time;
                    }
                    break;
                case States.DISAPPEARING:
                    if ((now_time[count] = System.currentTimeMillis() - prev_time[count]) >=15) {
                        current_radius[count] = current_radius[count] -3;
                        if (current_radius[count] <=1) {
                            state[count] = States.NONE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                        try {
                            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                Log.d("canvas","disappearing in count = "+String.valueOf(count));
                                canvas.drawCircle(x[count], y[count], current_radius[count], paint[count]);
                            }
                        }
                        finally {
                            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                            prev_time[count] = now_time[count];
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: you code is too long. try to do some refactoring and point to the part that creates the figures.

Comment: Attach a debugger or add some logging and figure out what it's doing and why that's different from what you want it to be doing.  Unless there's more to the problem than you've described, this seems like a straightforward logic debugging issue.